# Recursive number digits power n sum => is there a limit of unique result numbers found?

Tags: recursive-algorithms

Say you have a number *xyz* and you choose to split it to digits, take a power of each digit to three and summarize them. Some numbers gives same result than the original number, [for example](http://aa.aa):

153 = 1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3 = 153

4210818 = 4^7 + 2^7 + 1^7 + 0^7 + 8^7 + 1^7 + 8^7 = 4210818

Then some numbers gives other number, but when you recursively create a new number with the same algorithm from the result, you tend to find out certain list of numbers that are reductive end numbers. Like:

1080 => 1^3 + 0^3 + 8^3 + 0^3 = 513 => 5^3 + 1^3 + 3^3 = 153 = 1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3

Where 153 is the reductive end number.

For the power of 3 I have found 15 reductive numbers (1, 55, 133, 136, 153, 160, 217, 244, 250, 352, 370, 371, 407, 919, 1459). Most of them reduces to 153 & 371. I cannot find any new reductive pow numbers after 479 (tried with a limit of 50000). So the smallest reduce able number (SRN) to provide all reductive pow numbers is 479. Maximum recursive iteration needed to find out reductive pow numbers is 14 with a given limit.

> My questions are: Is there any mathematical way to prove that there are
>   no more reductive pow numbers after n? What kind of mathematical
>   problem domain this is, something to do with probability or
>   predictability or what?

I have created a table of pows from 2-9 that gives a summary of the results of the algorithm applied to certain limit of numbers.

```
EXP CORN    MPRN        HRV         MIOR    SRN     LIMIT
2   9       89          145         19      145     50000
3   15      153         1459        14      478     50000
4   13      13139       13139       58      11339   50000
5   95      9045        213040      75      58999   100000
6   39      383890      1458364     100     47778   100000
7   129     5905147     14628971    159     57889   100000
8   84      9514916     153362052   259     78999   100000
9   129     389778106   1430717631  186     66699   100000
```

EXP   = Exponent / Power
CORN  = Count of reduced numbers found between 1 and n (limit)
MPRN  = Most prominent reduced number, number that occurs most often as a result of reduction
HRV   = Highest reduced value
MIOR  = Maximum iterations occured on reductions
SRN   = Smallest reduce able number to find out all reduced values between 1 and n (limit)
LIMIT = Highest number to reduce

Finally I'd like to provide a picture to show the pattern of reduced pow 3 numbers:

[image: http://imageshack.us/a/img41/3184/ch8i.png]

Comment: Have a look at http://oeis.org/A124068 and the comments and cross-references there. I don't know what you mean by "last reductive number". Say, exponent 3; you list 1459 as a "reductive number", but you say 478 is the last reductive number. Anyway, it's easy enough to show that for any exponent $k$, there are only finitely many reductives, by showing that if $n$ is large enough then the sum of the $k$th powers of an $n$-digit number has fewer than $n$ digits. You'll also find these called "Armstrong numbers".

Comment: Yes, there is a small conceptual mistake there. 1459 is a biggest reductive end number. 479 is the smallest number, that gives all reductive end numbers when counted from 1 to 479. Or it is supposedly the smallest one, but because on other powers it gets bigger and bigger, it is also harder to detect. That's why I'm asking if there is a way to find out smallest number giving all reductive numbers, or at least if there is or isn't one.